# Build a timeline based on separate tables with multiple dateFrom and DateTo columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, gaps-and-islands, timeline

I have two tables, tblPrice and tblDiscount, each have their value with a liveFrom and liveUntil column (plus some other columns but I'm leaving those out to try and make this more straightforward).

What I'm trying to do is display a list of prices and discounts as an ordered list which will show how prices have changed based on the price changing or the discount changing.

*tblPrice*

| row | priceID | retailPrice | liveFrom | LiveUntil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 446413 | 1666.33 | 2022-01-31 11:36:21.490 | 2022-04-08 15:13:41.230 |
| 2 | 1338193 | 1666.33 | 2022-04-09 09:30:14.043 | 2023-04-05 09:37:21.767 |
| 3 | 2707357 | 1749.65 | 2023-04-05 09:37:21.767 | NULL |

*tblDiscount*

| row | logID | discount | liveFrom | LiveUntil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 192 | 0.3700 | 2022-01-31 11:27:45.060 | 2023-01-09 14:32:24.413 |
| 2 | 498 | 0.3200 | 2023-01-09 14:32:24.413 | 2023-04-11 15:40:06.460 |
| 3 | 639 | 0.3100 | 2023-04-11 15:40:06.460 | NULL |

*expected result*

| row | retailPrice | discount | liveFrom | liveUntil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1666.33 | 0.37 | 31/01/2022 11:36 | 08/04/2022 15:13 |
| 2 | 1666.33 | 0.37 | 09/04/2022 09:30 | 09/01/2023 14:32 |
| 3 | 1666.33 | 0.32 | 09/01/2023 14:32 | 05/04/2023 09:37 |
| 4 | 1749.65 | 0.32 | 05/04/2023 09:37 | 11/04/2023 15:40 |
| 5 | 1749.65 | 0.317 | 11/04/2023 15:40 | NULL |

Things to note are:

- Prices don't necessarily run continuously (note row 1 and 2 on tblPrice have no difference in price, it just happened to be ended and then restarted at a later date so this would give a period where there was no active price for the product).
- we're focusing on prices but a discount can be live while a price is not so in that situation the effective live from date would still need to be that of the price and not the discount.
- a price could be active without a discount so the effective discount would be 0

I've tried joining the tables on each other based on a date range and then using a case statement to show the live from and live until dates but it just doesn't seem right and I just can't quite get the logic. The results aren't coming up how I'd hope and I feel I'm going down a rabbit hole in the wrong direction.

My query so far (which as said I'm not sure is the right way to go) is:

```
SELECT
    P.[priceID],
    P.[retailPrice],
    P.[liveFrom],
    P.[liveUntil],
    D.[logID],
    D.[discount],
    D.[liveFrom],
    D.[liveUntil],
    ------------
    CASE
        WHEN SDV.[liveFrom] <= P.[liveFrom] AND (SDV.[liveUntil] >= P.[liveFrom] OR SDV.[liveUntil] IS NULL) THEN
            SDV.[liveFrom]
        WHEN SDV.[liveFrom] >= P.[liveFrom] AND (SDV.[liveUntil] <= P.[liveUntil] OR P.[liveUntil] IS NULL) THEN
            P.[liveFrom]
        ELSE
            '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
    END AS [EFFECTIVE_FROM],
    CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(P.[liveUntil],@date) < ISNULL(SDV.[liveUntil],@date) THEN
            P.[liveUntil]
        ELSE
            SDV.[liveUntil]
    END AS [EFFECTIVE_UNTIL]
FROM 
    tblPrice P
    INNER JOIN tblDiscount D ON P.[supplierDiscountID] = D.[supplierDiscountID]
        AND ((
                D.[liveFrom] <= P.[liveFrom] 
                AND (D.[liveUntil] >= P.[liveFrom] OR D.[liveUntil] IS NULL) 
            ) OR
            (
                D.[liveFrom] >= P.[liveFrom]
                AND (D.[liveFrom] <= P.[liveUntil] OR P.[liveUntil] IS NULL)
            ))
ORDER BY
    P.[liveFrom],
    D.[liveFrom];
```

I'm not getting the results I'm wanting and the route I'm going down just doesn't seem right. Can anybody give me any pointers or ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look for discount rows that begins before the price ends and ends after the price begins, so this could be a way to do it:

```
-- Sample data
declare @tblPrice table
    ( priceID int not null, retailPrice money not null
    , liveFrom datetime not null, liveUntil datetime)
declare @tblDiscount table
    ( logID int not null, discount decimal(5,4) not null
    , liveFrom datetime not null, liveUntil datetime)
insert into @tblPrice values
     ( 446413,1666.33,'2022-01-31T11:36:21.490','2022-04-08T15:13:41.230')
    ,(1338193,1666.33,'2022-04-09T09:30:14.043','2023-04-05T09:37:21.767')
    ,(2707357,1749.65,'2023-04-05T09:37:21.767', null)
insert into @tblDiscount values
     (192, 0.37, '2022-01-31T11:27:45.060','2023-01-09T14:32:24.413')
    ,(498, 0.32, '2023-01-09T14:32:24.413','2023-04-11T15:40:06.460')
    ,(639, 0.317,'2023-04-11T15:40:06.460', null)

-- Prices with discounts available or without any discount
select P.retailPrice
    , isNull(D.discount, 0) as discount
    , case when P.liveFrom  >= isNull(D.liveFrom, P.liveFrom)
        then P.liveFrom
        else D.liveFrom
      end as liveFrom
    , case when P.liveUntil <= isNull(D.liveUntil, P.liveUntil)
        then P.liveUntil
        else D.liveUntil
      end as liveUntil
from @tblPrice P
left join @tblDiscount D on
     -- P.supplierDiscountID = D.supplierDiscountID and
     D.liveFrom <= isNull(P.liveUntil, getDate())
 and P.liveFrom <= isNull(D.liveUntil, getDate())

union all
-- Prices that begins before 1st discount available
select x.retailPrice
    , 0 as discount
    , x.liveFrom
    , x.lf as liveUntil
from (
select P.retailPrice, P.liveFrom
    , min(D.liveFrom) lf
from @tblPrice P
left join @tblDiscount D on
     -- P.supplierDiscountID = D.supplierDiscountID and
     D.liveFrom <= isNull(P.liveUntil, getDate())
 and P.liveFrom <= isNull(D.liveUntil, getDate())
group by P.priceID, P.retailPrice, P.liveFrom
having min(D.liveFrom)
     > P.liveFrom
) x

union all
-- Prices that ends after last discount available
select x.retailPrice
    , 0 as discount
    , x.lu as liveFrom
    , x.liveUntil
from (
select P.retailPrice, P.liveUntil
    , max(isNull(D.liveUntil, getDate())) lu
from @tblPrice P
left join @tblDiscount D on
     -- P.supplierDiscountID = D.supplierDiscountID and
     D.liveFrom <= isNull(P.liveUntil, getDate())
 and P.liveFrom <= isNull(D.liveUntil, getDate())
group by P.priceID, P.retailPrice, P.liveUntil
having max(isNull(D.liveUntil, getDate()))
     < isNull(P.liveUntil, getDate())
) x

order by liveFrom
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @xabi. I think I was trying to over complicate things by trying to do it in a single select instead of using a union and was just going down the wrong road. It makes complete sense what you've suggested so thankyou very much.

Comment: YW, @ahhHelp and, if you consider my answer is useful for you, please mark the solution as accepted. Thanks ;-)